# "Security" of SHA functions (Wikipedia), what does it mean?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, security-definition, sha-2

Wikepedia's table [Comparison of SHA functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Comparison_of_SHA_functions) mentions "Security(bits)" for some SHA functions. From the ratio (Output size (bits): Security(bits)), I feel it is something like "collision resistance". So,

Should we only consider collision resistance as the Security of a hash function?

what does the Security in the table mean?

Comment: One of our [top contributors](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/351/d-w) uses exactly the same nick name as you. So it might be a good idea to change your name, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security in the table refers to collision resistance. By the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), there's a generic attack that finds collisions in any compressing function by choosing $\sqrt{2^m}$ random inputs ($m/2$ security bits), where $m$ is the output length.

Depending on the application, weaker requirements might be sufficient, such as second pre-image resistance or even one-wayness. A generic attack against the two weaker notions requires about $2^m$ work ($m$ security bits).